# Django LEFT OUTER JOIN on TWO columns where one isn't a foreign key

Tags: sql, django, join

I have two models like so:

```
class ObjectLock(models.Model):
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('partner', 'object_id'),)

class ObjectImportQueue(models.Model):
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ... # other fields
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('modified', 'created')
```

There is nothing notable about the third model mentioned above (Partner).

I'd like to get something like:

```
SELECT * FROM ObjectImportQueue q LEFT OUTER JOIN ObjectLock l ON
q.partner_id=l.partner_id AND q.object_id=l.object_id WHERE l.object_id
IS NULL and l.partner_id IS NULL;
```

I came across [this page](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/09/28/custom-joins-with-djangos-queryjoin/) that tells how to do custom joins, and I tried passing in a tuple of the column names to join in place of the column name to join, and that didn't work. The Partner table shouldn't need to be included in the resulting sql query but I will accept an answer that does include it as long as it effectively does what I'm trying to do with one query.

Comment: Maybe I got something wrong here, but why not look for object_id = NULL and partner_id = NULL without joining? should give you the same results?

Comment: I'm trying to find rows in the queue table that do _not_ have a corresponding row in the lock table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also meet a similar question.but finally,I found I asked a wrong question to be solve.

in the Django ORM,the condition of SQL join is base on what the `models.Model` fields defined.

there are Many-to-one relationships (`ForeignKey`),Many-to-many relationships(`ManyToManyField`),One-to-one relationships(`OneToOneField`).

in your situation.`ObjectLock`Model and `ObjectImportQueue`Model have the same part of fields, the `partner`field and `object_id`field.yon should use One-to-one relationships.

you can change your Model like this:

```
class ObjectImportQueue(models.Model):
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, db_index=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s:%s" % (self.partner, self.object_id)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('modified', 'created')

class ObjectLock(models.Model):
    lock = models.OneToOneField(ObjectImportQueue, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('lock',),)
```

order of Model is import,`OneToOneField` argument model must come first.

```
>>> p1 = Partner.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> p2 = Partner.objects.get(pk=2)
>>> Q1 = ObjectImportQueue.objects.create(partner=p1,object_id='id_Q1')
>>> Q2 = ObjectImportQueue.objects.create(partner=p2,object_id='id_Q2')
>>> ObjectImportQueue.objects.filter(lock__isnull=True)
[<ObjectImportQueue: Partner object:id_Q1>, <ObjectImportQueue: Partner object:id_Q2>]
>>> L1 = ObjectLock.objects.create(lock=Q1)
>>> ObjectImportQueue.objects.filter(lock__isnull=True)
[<ObjectImportQueue: Partner object:id_Q2>]
```

`ObjectLock.objects.create`lock a object
`ObjectImportQueue.objects.filter(lock__isnull=True)` select object don't be lock.

if you use the appropriate relationships, generate the ORM query will be easy.In Django，Define the relationships during you build the Model is better than use Query statement to relation the relationships between tables.

Comment: Best answer for my specific case, I think. But I asked the question so long ago, I don't know if it would *actually* work, but I suppose it should. Marking as answer. This is *not* the best general answer for "left outer join on two columns".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711547/converting-left-outer-join-query-to-django-orm-queryset-query maybe this helpful

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Django 1.2+ and know the SQL you want, you could always fall back to a [Raw Query.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to this problem.

You have to create a view that does the join for you

```
CREATE VIEW ImporQueueLock AS (
  SELECT q.id, l.id
    FROM ObjectImportQueue q
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ObjectLock l
        ON q.partner_id=l.partner_id AND q.object_id=l.object_id
  )
```

Then make a django model for that view

```
class ImportQueueLock(models.Model):

    queue = models.ForeignKey(ObjectImportQueue, db_column='q')
    lock = models.ForeignKey(ObjectLock, db_column='l')
```

Then make a ManyToMany on your Django model from ObjectLock to ObjectImportQueue through ImportQueueLock

```
class ObjectLock(models.Model):
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    queue = models.ManyToManyField(ObjectImportQueue, through = ImportQueueLock)
```

and you will be able to do

```
ObjectLock.objects.filter(importqueuelock__objectimportqueue__ .....)
```