# Converting LEFT OUTER JOIN query to Django orm queryset/query

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, orm

Given PostgreSQL 9.2.10, Django 1.8, python 2.7.5 and the following models:

```
class restProdAPI(models.Model):
    rest_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    rest_host = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rest_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(default='0.0.0.0')
    rest_mode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rest_state = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class soapProdAPI(models.Model):
    soap_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    soap_host = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    soap_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(default='0.0.0.0')
    soap_asset = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    soap_state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

And the following raw query which returns exactly what I am looking for:

```
SELECT
    app_restProdAPI.rest_id, app_soapProdAPI.soap_id, app_restProdAPI.rest_host, app_restProdAPI.rest_ip, app_soapProdAPI.soap_asset, app_restProdAPI.rest_mode, app_restProdAPI.rest_state
FROM
    app_soapProdAPI
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    app_restProdAPI
ON
    ((app_restProdAPI.rest_host = app_soapProdAPI.soap_host)
OR
    (app_restProdAPI.rest_ip = app_soapProdAPI.soap_ip))
WHERE 
    app_restProdAPI.rest_mode = 'Excluded';
```

Which returns like this:

```
 rest_id | soap_id |   rest_host   |     rest_ip    | soap_asset | rest_mode | rest_state
---------+---------+---------------+----------------+------------+-----------+-----------
   1234  |  12345  | 1G24019123ABC | 123.123.123.12 |  A1234567  | Excluded  |     Up
```

What would be the best method for making this work using Django's model and orm structure?

I have been looking around for possible methods for joining the two tables entirely without a relationship but there does not seem to be a clean or efficient way to do this. I have also tried looking for methods to do left outer joins in django, but again documentation is sparse or difficult to decipher.

I know I will probably have to use `Q` objects to do the or clause I have in there. Additionally I have looked at relationships and it looks like a `foreignkey()` may work but I am unsure if this is the best method of doing it. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

** **EDIT 1** **

So far Todor has offered a solution that uses a INNER JOIN that works. I may have found a solution **[HERE](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/09/28/custom-joins-with-djangos-queryjoin/)** if anyone can decipher that mess of inline raw html.

** **EDIT 2** **

Is there a way to filter on a field (where something = 'something') like my query above given, Todor's answer? I tried the following but it is still including all records even though my equivalent postresql query is working as expected. It seems I cannot have everything in the where that I do because when I remove one of the or statements and just do a and statement it applies the excluded filter.

```
soapProdAPI.objects.extra(
    select = {
        'rest_id'    : 'app_restprodapi.rest_id',
        'rest_host'  : 'app_restprodapi.rest_host',
        'rest_ip'    : 'app_restprodapi.rest_ip',
        'rest_mode'  : 'app_restprodapi.rest_mode',
        'rest_state' : 'app_restprodapi.rest_state'
    },
    tables = ['app_restprodapi'],
    where  = ['app_restprodapi.rest_mode=%s \
               AND app_restprodapi.rest_host=app_soapprodapi.soap_host \
               OR app_restprodapi.rest_ip=app_soapprodapi.soap_ip'],
    params = ['Excluded']
    )
```

---

** **EDIT 3 / CURRENT SOLUTION IN PLACE** **

To date Todor has provided the most complete answer, using an INNER JOIN, but the hope is that this question will generate thought into how this still may be accomplished. As this does not seem to be inherently possible, any and all suggestions are welcome as they may possibly lead to better solutions. That being said, using Todor's answer, I was able accomplish the exact query I needed:

```
restProdAPI.objects.extra(
    select = {
        'soap_id'    : 'app_soapprodapi.soap_id',
        'soap_asset' : 'app_soapprodapi.soap_asset'
    },
    tables = ['app_soapprodapi'],
    where  = ['app_restprodapi.rest_mode = %s',
              'app_soapprodapi.soap_host = app_restprodapi.rest_host OR \
               app_soapprodapi.soap_ip   = app_restprodapi.rest_ip'
    ],
    params = ['Excluded']
    )
```

---

** **TLDR** **

I would like to convert this PostGreSQL query to the ORM provided by Django ***WITHOUT using `.raw()` or any raw query code at all***. I am completely open to changing the model to having a foreignkey if that facilitates this and is, from a performance standpoint, the best method. I am going to be using the objects returned in conjunction with [django-datatables-view](https://bitbucket.org/pigletto/django-datatables-view) if that helps in terms of design.

Comment: Is `INNER JOIN` suitable for you instead of `LEFT JOIN` ? I can show you a way with `.extra`, but the result of the query will be more like a using `INNER JOIN` in your example.

Comment: @Todor I am open to, and greatly appreciate, all suggestions that meet the **tldr** acceptance criteria. Or if it is felt that my acceptance criteria is unreasonable or wrong, please explain why and I will revise accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solving it with INNER JOIN

In case you can go with only `soapProdAPI's` that contain corresponding `restProdAPI` *( in terms of your join statement -> linked by host or ip)*. You can try the following:

```
soapProdAPI.objects.extra(
    select = {
        'rest_id'   : "app_restProdAPI.rest_id",
        'rest_host' : "app_restProdAPI.rest_host",
        'rest_ip'   : "app_restProdAPI.rest_ip",
        'rest_mode' : "app_restProdAPI.rest_mode",
        'rest_state': "app_restProdAPI.rest_state"
    },
    tables = ["app_restProdAPI"],
    where = ["app_restProdAPI.rest_host = app_soapProdAPI.soap_host \
              OR app_restProdAPI.rest_ip = app_soapProdAPI.soap_ip"]
)
```

**How to filter more?**

Since we are using [`.extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#extra) I would advice to read the docs carefully. In general we can't use `.filter` with some of the fields inside the `select` dict, because they are not part of the `soapProdAPI` and Django can't resolve them. We have to stick with the `where` `kwarg` in `.extra`, and since it's a list, we better just add another element.

```
    where = ["app_restProdAPI.rest_host = app_soapProdAPI.soap_host \
              OR app_restProdAPI.rest_ip = app_soapProdAPI.soap_ip",
             "app_restProdAPI.rest_mode=%s"
    ],
    params = ['Excluded']
```

#### Repeated subquery

If you really need all `soapProdAPI's` no matter if they have corresponding `restProdAPI` I can only think of a one ugly example where a `subquery` is repeated for each field you need.

```
soapProdAPI.objects.extra(
    select = {
        'rest_id'   : "(select rest_id from app_restProdAPI where app_restProdAPI.rest_host = app_soapProdAPI.soap_host OR app_restProdAPI.rest_ip = app_soapProdAPI.soap_ip)",
        'rest_host' : "(select rest_host from app_restProdAPI where app_restProdAPI.rest_host = app_soapProdAPI.soap_host OR app_restProdAPI.rest_ip = app_soapProdAPI.soap_ip)",
        'rest_ip'   : "(select rest_ip from app_restProdAPI where app_restProdAPI.rest_host = app_soapProdAPI.soap_host OR app_restProdAPI.rest_ip = app_soapProdAPI.soap_ip)",
        'rest_mode' : "(select rest_mode from app_restProdAPI where app_restProdAPI.rest_host = app_soapProdAPI.soap_host OR app_restProdAPI.rest_ip = app_soapProdAPI.soap_ip)",
        'rest_state': "(select rest_state from app_restProdAPI where app_restProdAPI.rest_host = app_soapProdAPI.soap_host OR app_restProdAPI.rest_ip = app_soapProdAPI.soap_ip)"
    },
)
```

Comment: I get the following error with your first query: ProgrammingError: relation "app_restProdAPI" does not exist. ...oapprodapi"."soap_state" FROM "app_soapprodapi" , "app_rest_... Which looks like it is having an issue right at the Join unless I am reading it wrong.

Comment: I think you are not referencing the table name correctly. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695289/cannot-simply-use-postgresql-table-name-relation-does-not-exist) answer.

Comment: ahh I got it. so I logged into psql and did a \c to the database in question then did a \d on the database and got this: app_restprodapi . explains it.

Comment: So other than extra which kinda sorta uses raw sql code is there no real method for doing a join like defined the postgresql query I wrote? I am still really new to django but it seems odd that the ORM cannot handle joins between unrelated tables all to well.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no real `.join()` method in the `ORM`.

Comment: the solution you have provided kind of works. It returns objects that have all soapProdAPI fields but I am unable to get any of the restProdAPI fields. Please see the edit in my question. There is **[THIS](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/09/28/custom-joins-with-djangos-queryjoin/)** (the html is broken as hell). It's from 2009 so it is crusty but possibly a solution?

Comment: I made a clean version of the article [here](http://pastebin.com/GwTFjgRr). Honesty I'm not sure about this. even if it works I'll probably won't use it.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear that you can't get any of the `restProdAPI`? With the solution I gave every `soapProdAPI` object in the `queryset` should have fields like `.rest_id`, `rest_host`, ... , `rest_state`.

Comment: Thanks, I will look it over. And ignore my 'it's not working fully' comment, I think I figured out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: how would I through a filter(rest_mode='Excluded') in there? As I stated I am using this with django-datatables-view and displaying tables per rest_mode. I updated my postgresql query and returned results if that helps. Or is it as simple as multiple where clauses in the extra query?

Comment: Check my edited answer. You basically did it correct, but it's not working for you because you have missed to put brackets to separate the logical statements. If you add it as another element in the list, Django will take care of that. I'm not using it in the first place intentionally because I want `OR` between the `host` and `ip` and Django concatenates  with `AND` by default.

Comment: Damn. And I even RTFM but I guess I just spaced on this one. Thanks for all your help, you are a godsend.

Comment: Marking as the correct answer as this seems to be the best method baring creating a relation and doing a select related.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be usefull for you! Effectively, you can use Q to construct your query. 
I try it the Django shell, I create some data  and I did something like this:

```
restProdAPI.objects.filter(Q(rest_host=s1.soap_host)|Q(rest_ip=s1.soap_ip))
```

Where s1 is a soapProdAPI.

This is all the code i whote, you can try it and to see if can help you

```
from django.db.models import Q
from core.models import restProdAPI, soapProdAPI

s1 =  soapProdAPI.objects.get(soap_id=1)

restProdAPI.objects.filter(Q(rest_id=s1.soap_id)|Q(rest_ip=s1.soap_ip))
```

Comment: It is a start in that it actually completes where mine did not. Now I just need to figure out how to get the `soap_id` and `soap_asset` to be included in the resulting object and then get it to work for all records.